# Not able to call event through ElapsedEventHandler in windows service in C# .Net

Tags: c#, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to write a service that runs a task of creating crystal reports. I am calling a method "timer_Elapsed" in Start by using ElapsedEventHandler. But this method is not being called.

any help regarding that will be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
public void Start()
        {
           // OnStart(new string[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("Windows Service Started");
            timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.timer1)).BeginInit();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            this.timer1.Interval = 2000;
            this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer_Elapsed);
            this.timer1.Interval = 2000;
            //timer1.Enabled = true;
            Log("Service Started successfully!!");
            timeCurrent = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            Log("Service Started at" + " " + timeCurrent);
        }


private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GenerateCrystalReports();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Start` on the timer to actually start it.